# Translate not working for some strings

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using [Drupal commons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commons). I am using [I18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and other related modules for my website as it is created in English but is being used in French also. I am using translations provided. My issue is that I have string translations but for some strings, text is not being translated, although the translations are available in the drupal.
[image]

**UPDATE**
After going through code, I found that this "Request Message" field is not a normal form field, but it is being rendered using

```
     field_attach_form('og_membership', $og_membership, $form['membership_fields'], $form_state);
```

The issue is with this "**field_attach_form()**". Do ANYONE have any idea what can be done for this??

Comment: Which strings?  The first step is to isolate where the strings that are not being translated are being provided from (are they hard-coded into a module?  added through the Views UI? etc.)

Comment: those strings are mostly hardcoded in modules.. those are mostly GUI options, like I am using Organic Groups and there is registration for the groups. In add-user page of group I have fields, some are getting translated while some are not, like request message field label and description is not getting translated

Comment: I hope you getting what I mean or I will attach a screenshot soon

Comment: Try refreshing strings and clearing caches.

Comment: yes I tried that too but nothing worked

Comment: I have added the screenshot how some fields are translated but some not, although translations of non-translated fields are available

Comment: i18n issues can be difficult to trace, but there are probably multiple problems here.  I would start by searching drupal.org for Organic Groups i18n issues, and see how good/bad the situation is.  If some types of fields are translated but not others, than I would run a google search for the field that is not being translated correctly.

Comment: After going through code, I found that this "Request Message" field is not a normal form field, but it is being rendered using  field_attach_form('og_membership', $og_membership, $form['membership_fields'], $form_state);. The issue is with this "field_attach_form()". Do you have any idea what can be done for this??

Comment: try to change it to field_attach_form('og_membership', $og_membership, $form['membership_fields'], $form_state, 'fr');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I know this solution is not best and structural method and is better solve this issue but sometimes we just need a solution and want save the time(maybe it be some issue with commons distributes.
Sometimes I do this trick in some projects

if you want translate all `keystring`  in every where use

```
 $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/keystring /g, "TranslateString"));
```

and also if you want only some specified(with specified class and page class) string use

```
$('.checkout-review .field-name-phone-mobile .field-label').html($('.checkout-review .field-name-phone-mobile .field-label').html().replace(/keystring /g, "TranslateString"));
```

You just need put one of them in JS file.

Comment: Yes, this solution is not best, but din't get any other solution, so have to use this only. Thanks, it was quick trick, accepting your answer.

Comment: @Drupaler your welcome, I know this is not best solution but sometimes we should save our times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's language translation can be hit or miss sometimes. Often times its silly little pieces like the part that you mentioned that dont get translated while 95% of the rest of the page translate without issues. Google to the rescue!! I recommend the [Gtranslate](https://www.drupal.org/project/gtranslate) module to get you started and of course you can place the [google translate api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) directly into a tpl or module file to get the full monty!!